# Homework Help: Why won't variables return

Tags: java, methods, input

I can't figure this out

My variables aren't returning to print in the output message I have no idea where I am going wrong and my teacher tells me to go through the code line by line and check for logic and syntax errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package selfhelpstore;  
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  
public class SelfHelpStore {  
    private static String getStringInput(String prompt) {  
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);  
        String nullFlag = "n";
        int i = 1;
        while (i<=2)
        if (input == null) {
            System.exit(0);
        }else if (input.isEmpty()) {
            i++;
            nullFlag = "y";
            prompt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Re-enter: ");
        } else {
            i=4;
            nullFlag = "n";
        }
        if (!input.isEmpty()) {
            nullFlag = "n";
        }
        if (nullFlag.equals("y")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Null or blank - exiting...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return prompt;
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String openingMsg, nameInputMsg, customerName, nameOutputMsg, 
               returnInputMsg, customerReturn, returnOutputMsg, 
               greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg,coverInputMsg, coverMsg ;

        openingMsg = "*** Welcome to Self Help Book Store Online Ordering System ***\n"
                   + "                     It's a great day to read a book!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, openingMsg);

        nameInputMsg   = getStringInput("Please enter your name: ");   
                customerName   = nameInputMsg;
                returnInputMsg = getStringInput("Are you a returning customer (yes or no)?     ");
        customerReturn = returnInputMsg;
                coverInputMsg = getStringInput("would you like this book in hard cover or     paper back?");
                coverMsg = coverInputMsg;

        nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n\n";
        returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
        greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for visiting our Self Help Book Store!" + "\n"
                        + "Your " + coverMsg + " should be mailed in less than two     business days.\n";

        outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputMsg);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all please indent correctly or I will die before being able to help

Comment: Ditto on the first comment, this makes it so hard to understand what is going on. and remove all the useless comments and white space.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflows happy to answer specific programming questions, or assist with specific roadblocks in code, but we won't be going through it to give you the answer. As @realUser404 says, a good first step is to indent carefully, but then you'll have to do as your teacher says and go through it line by line until you find the part that's not working. This is the most effective way to learn. =)

Comment: 2nd, I believe your IDE has a "debug" tool. You just need to put a "stop" at the first line of you method, then as your teacher says, just go line by line and check value of your variables. You will then be able to find the error really easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getStringInput method is returning the variable prompt, when you want it to return input.

```
private static String getStringInput(String prompt) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);

    String nullFlag = "n";
    int i = 1;
    while(i <= 2)

        if(input == null)

        {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if(input.isEmpty())

        {
            i++;
            nullFlag = "y";
            prompt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Re-enter: ");
        } else {
            i = 4;
            nullFlag = "n";
        }

    if(!input.isEmpty()) {
        nullFlag = "n";
    }

    if(nullFlag.equals("y")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Null or blank - exiting...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return input;  // Change this line
}
```